# Insert byte[] into blob field with spring's jdbcTemplate and stored procedure

Tags: spring, firebird, jdbctemplate, jaybird

I'm try to insert `byte[]` into blob field with stored procedure, and get an Exception :

> Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [SELECT ID FROM sp_NEWFILE(?,?,?)]; nested exception is org.firebirdsql.jdbc.field.TypeConversionException: Error converting to object.

Model:

```java
public class fileBody { 
private int ID;
private byte[] BODY;
private String FILENAME; //getters an setters}
```

Insert it to database

```
public class FileBodyDaoImpl implements FileBodyDao {

public int insertData(final FileBody fileBody) throws IOException {     
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    LobHandler lobHandler = new DefaultLobHandler();        
    final InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBody.getBODY());
    final int fileSize = in.available();
    Map<String, Object> out = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT ID FROM  sp_NEWFILE(?,?,?)",
            new AbstractLobCreatingPreparedStatementCallback(lobHandler) {
                protected void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, LobCreator lobCreator) throws SQLException,
                        DataAccessException {
                    ps.setString(1, fileBody.getFILENAME());
                    lobCreator.setBlobAsBinaryStream(ps, 2, in, fileSize);
                    ps.setNull(3, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
                }
            });     
    int last_inserted = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(out.get("ID")));
    return last_inserted;
}
```

And my stored procedure

```sql
create or alter procedure sp_NEWFILE (
FILENAME varchar(255),
BODY blob sub_type 0 segment size 80,
USEID integer)
returns (
ID integer)
as
begin
  if (useid is not null) then ID=USEID;
  else ID=GEN_ID(gen_filebody_id,1);
  if ((FILENAME is NULL) or (FILENAME=''))  then FILENAME='UNDEFINED';
  INSERT INTO  t_filebody(ID,BODY,FILENAME) VALUES(:ID,:BODY,:FILENAME);
  suspend;
end^
```

and i get an Exception:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: 
PreparedStatementCallback; 
bad SQL grammar [SELECT ID FROM sp_NEWFILE(?,?,?)]; nested exception is org.firebirdsql.jdbc.field.TypeConversionException: Error converting to object.
```

Versions:
jaybird-jdk17-2.2.5;
Source: firebird2.5 Version: 2.5.1.26351.ds4-2ubuntu0.1;

Comment: Could you include the full stacktrace and specify the Jaybird and Firebird version you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that [`queryForMap`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForMap-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-) does not support a `PreparedStatementCallback` (contrary to for example [`execute`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#execute-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.PreparedStatementCallback-)), instead your anonymous object is considered a normal parameter for the query to execute, and Jaybird does not support this object type. And if Jaybird had supported it, you would have received an error for missing parameters 2 and 3.

Your code can be greatly simplified by passing the byte array:

```java
Map<String, Object> out = jdbcTemplate.queryForMap("SELECT ID FROM sp_NEWFILE(?,?,?)",
        fileBody.getFILENAME(), fileBody.getBODY(), null);
```

This works as Jaybird considers a `BLOB SUB_TYPE 0` as a `java.sql.Types.LONGVARBINARY` and JDBC 4.2 appendix B declares that `byte[]` is the default type for that (although you can also use it as a `java.sql.Types.BLOB`).

As a side note, your stored procedure does not need to be selectable (removing `SUSPEND` makes it executable), and the procedure could also be replaced by using a [`TRIGGER`](http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/) to generate the primary key and retrieving the value either by using [`INSERT .. RETURNING ..`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-insert-returning) or through the JDBC generated keys facility (which in turn is implemented in Jaybird through `INSERT .. RETURNING ..`).

Answer (score 0):

For those seeking non-Jaybird solution to insert BLOB using spring jdbctemplate, the following syntax worked for me to use stored procedures which is different compared to insert via queries.

Insert via Queries

```
ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
ps.setBlob(1, inputStream);
```

Insert via Stored Procedure Call

```
    Map<String, Object> inParams = new HashMap<>();
    inParams.put("pi_some_id", id);
    inParams.put("pi_file_blob",  new SqlLobValue(file.getBytes()));        
    SqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource(inParams);        
    SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = {
                    new SqlParameter("pi_some_id", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("pi_file_blob", Types.BLOB),
                    new SqlOutParameter("po_error_flag", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlOutParameter("po_message", Types.VARCHAR)};
            
    SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withoutProcedureColumnMetaDataAccess().
withProcedureName(storedProcName).withCatalogName(packageName).
declareParameters(sqlParameters);
    Map<String, Object> storedProcResult = simpleJdbcCall.execute(sqlParameterSource);
```